# Why does pandas have a naming convention which mixes CamelCase and lowercase with underscores?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading [10min to pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html). The naming convention confuses me. Why does it use UpperCase sometimes and lower_case with underscore at other times?

Two examples:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Can someone explain to me why it is like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the usual Python naming convention. `pd.DataFrame` is a class, so it is in [CapWords case](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names), and `pd.date_range` is a function, so it is in [snake_case](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names).

You can read more in the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python's style guide.